# 'Add Google Groups or Google+ Communities' for Alpha testing doesnt' work

Tags: beta-testing

To proceed Alpha testing, I created a Google+ Community to manage beta user group and communicate with them.

But when I add the URL of Google+ Communities, it says 'No Group or Community found.' Have Anyone experienced the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you are adding newer links, try to add older version link. see below

**Newer Link** https://plus.google.com/b/117500750877015255663/communities/104473318520257515492

**Older Link** 
https://plus.google.com/communities/104473318520257515492

You may just need to remove below parts from newer URLs

```
/b/117500750877015255663
```